# How to set subplots in one Figure in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, figure

I simply want to align my subplots within my figure in the following way:

Using this code:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(131)
a = ax1.imshow(im,interpolation='none',origin='lower')
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(132)
b = ax2.imshow(best_fit,origin='lower')
ax3 = fig.add_subplot(133)
c = ax3.imshow(residual,interpolation='none',origin='lower')
ax4 = fig.add_subplot(123)
d = ax3.imshow(correlation_mat,interpolation='none',origin='lower',vmin=-1,vmax=1)
```

I want to create the figure such that plots a,b and c are all in one column on the left and then have d occupy most of the space on the right side of the plot. I know that this should be indicated in the

```
fig.add_subplot()
```

line, but I'm not sure how to do it.

Comment: You might want to take a look at http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/demo_tight_layout.html

Comment: The gridspec library handles it quite well!

Comment: you also might want to have a look on this:
http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/jrjohansson/scientific-python-lectures/blob/master/Lecture-4-Matplotlib.ipynb
on the page you have to search for gridspec and subplot2grid

Answer (score 4):

subplot2grid is a very nice feature for more complicated layouts. You define a grid and add axes to it at the grid positions, in this case i used 3 cols and 3 rows. You can define a row- and colspan for axes covering more than one grid position.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt                                                  

fig = plt.figure()                                                               

ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((3,3), (0,0))                                             
ax2 = plt.subplot2grid((3,3), (1,0))                                             
ax3 = plt.subplot2grid((3,3), (2,0))                                             
ax3 = plt.subplot2grid((3,3), (0,1), rowspan=3, colspan=2)                       
fig.tight_layout()
```

Result looks like this:[image: plot result]